# Amazon EC2 instance cannot resolve hostnames

Tags: amazon-ec2, nameserver

My free tier EC2 instance (ubuntu 11.04, created last year) is expired. I just created a new one (ubuntu 12.04), but found that the new EC2 cannot resolve any hostname. By checking `/etc/resolv.conf`.

The old one looks like:

```
domain ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
search ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
nameserver 172.16.0.23
```

Where the new one looks like:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Is the nameserver configuration not automatically set up now? How should I configure the nameserver, through the AWS console? Do I have to use Route 53? I would rather use a free solution if it's not too complicated to set up.

Comment: That is strange, `resolve.conf` should not be empty. Did you use the stock Ubuntu 12.04 AMI or did you use a community AMI to create your instance?

Comment: I picked the one from "quick start" list. AMI full name: Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was curious so I just launched an instance using AMI "Ubuntu Server 12.04.2 LTS" and I have this in resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 172.16.0.23
search us-west-2.compute.internal
```

So maybe something went wrong when you created your instance. Try launching a new one.

**Edit**: Since your instance is inside a VPC, try [Creating a DHCP Options Set](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#CreatingaDHCPOptionSet) with `domain-name-servers=AmazonProvidedDNS`, then assign the options set to your VPC.

Comment: My resolv.conf is same as yours. But after rebooting the instance in the AWS console, the resolv.conf is gone. How can I get it back?

Comment: Is your instance inside a VPC?

Comment: Yes, it got a VPC id.

Comment: See my edit about VPC.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I appear to have observed: when I skipped the configure steps in the Create Wizard, my instance had an empty `resolv.conf`, but when I clicked through the steps (didn't change the defaults, just clicked through dutifully), then the resolution configuration had the nameserver in it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the DNS options for your VPC.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html
You can add your private DNS there, and instead of adding the AWS DNS server, the DHCP update will put the addresses you have configured.

Comment: Please expand your answer to include relevant details from the link, so that when the content linked to disappears, your answer is still useful.